# jsp, servlets, faces and beans?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets, javabeans

i´ve read a little about java's structure and could someone tell me if my view of all these components are correct:

```
JSP corresponds a View
Servlet corresponds a Controller
Bean corresponds a Model
Faces correspond layouts to render display
```

is this roughly correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSPs are view technology - HTML with Java embedded in it.
Servlets should be used as controllers - they're Java classes that implement methods to read and write HTTP streams.
In a web app Javabeans are usually the model - JSPs and other Java view technologies understand how to access properties of Javabeans, bind them to forms, etc.
Faces is a separate stack JSF (Java Server Faces) is a component based web framework.

Comment: HTML with raw Java code embedded (using scriptlets) is discouraged since over a decade. You're supposed to use taglibs like JSTL to control the JSP page flow Expression Language to access any scoped attributes.

Comment: Agreed - I was just trying for a short description.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're roughly correct.

Only, the `Faces` is more than just "layouts to render a display". [JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html) is a full fledged component based MVC framework which is built on top of the Servlet API. It uses the `FacesServlet` as the sole controller. It used to use JSP as view technology, which is now replaced by [Facelets](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) (XHTML) as per the new JSF 2.0 API. It uses the so-called [backing beans](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gjaam.html#gjacb) as model. Then, you have [taglibs/components](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnarf.html) which can be used in the view layer to generate HTML and uses [Expression Language](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) to associate the data/events with the model objects (the managed beans).